# Evaluation of Add/Edit view function

Tags: django

I have a view function that allows a user to Add / Edit / Delete an object. How does the following function look, and in what ways could I improve it? I was thinking about separating aspects of the function into different parts, but since no 'component' is more than four-five lines of code, I thought that would be a bit overkill.

```
@login_required
def edit_education(request, edit=0):
    profile = request.user.get_profile()
    education = profile.education_set.order_by('-class_year')
    form = EducationForm(data=request.POST or None, request=request)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        ##### to add a new school entry ######
        if 'add_school' in request.POST:
            if form.is_valid():
                new_education = form.save(commit=False)
                new_education.user = profile
                new_education.save()
                return redirect('edit_education')

        ##### to delete a school entry #####
        for education_id in [key[7:] for key, value in request.POST.iteritems() if key.startswith('delete')]:
            Education.objects.get(id=education_id).delete()
            return redirect('edit_education')

        ###### to edit a school entry -- essentially, re-renders the page passing an "edit" variable #####
        for education_id in [key[5:] for key, value in request.POST.iteritems() if key.startswith('edit')]:
            edit = 1
            school_object = Education.objects.get(id = education_id)
            form = EducationForm(instance = school_object, request=request)
            return render(request, 'userprofile/edit_education.html', 
                        {'form': form, 
                         'education':education, 
                         'edit': 1, 
                         'education_id': education_id}
                    )
        ##### to save changes after you edit a previously-added school entry ######
        if 'save_changes' in request.POST:
            instance = Education.objects.get(id=request.POST['education_id']) 
            form = EducationForm(data = request.POST, instance=instance, request=request, edit=1)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('edit_education')

return render(request, 'userprofile/edit_education.html', {'form': form, 'education': education})
```

And in my template, if this help to clarify anything:

```
{% for education in education %}
    <p><b>{{ education.school }}</b> {% if education.class_year %}{{ education.class_year|shorten_year}}, {% endif %} {{ education.degree}}
        <input type="submit" name="edit_{{education.id}}" value='Edit' />
        <input type="submit" name="delete_{{education.id}}" value="Delete" />
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you.

Comment: i would do all this via ajax, using piston or django-rest-framwork, a lot of changes but you dont need to reload your page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You get `education` from DB every time, but if you delete or add object, it isn't used. Extra request to DB with no use.
2. Same for form, you don't need it if you delete object. And you redefine it for edit and save_changes.
3. `add_school` logic is form-specific, no need to place it in view.
4. You often use something like `Education.objects.get(id=request.POST['education_id'])`. There is no validation or exception handling, which is bad.
5. You use `for` cycle over the list and `return` inside a cycle to process only the first item. This is very strange approach, if you need the first item just use `lst[0]`. Or if you need to process all the items `return` should be placed outside a cycle.

Comment: DrTyrsa: thank you very much for the feedback, this is very helpful. Just a few questions I had to help me better understand your points: for point 1) does `education = profile.education_set.order_by('-class_year')` call the database? I was under the impression the db was only called when it's evaluated (and not just defined). 3) in terms of taking the `add_school` logic out of the view, would you suggest overloading the form in forms.py? 4) what would be a better way to do `Education.objects.get(id=request.POST['education_id'])` ? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: 1). Yes, it isn't evaluated, my mistake, but it's still better to define variables only if you are going to use them. 3). Yes, you can pass `profile` to form's constructor or to `save` method. 4). Just put it in `try` block and catch `Education.DoesNotExists` exception.